# What does += mean in the context of event handling?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, interactive-brokers

In [Scanner data (streaming)](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/recipes.html#scanner-data-streaming) I can find the following statement (you can find below the full code):

`scanData.updateEvent += onScanData`

What does the `+=` mean?

So, I understand that `onScanData()` is the event handler function that should be called when the [`scanData.updateEvent`](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/e1bbd3f2ece56bd8b5e21d07514513fb8b7d421e/ib_insync/objects.py#L458) is fired.

But why do I have a `+=` here and not a simple `=`?
What get's incremented and where can I find the incremented variable later on?

Remark: to get the code snippet below running, the Interactive-Brokers software TWS has be running.

```
import datetime
from ib_insync import *

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)


def onScanData(scanData):
    print(scanData[0])
    print(len(scanData))

sub = ScannerSubscription(
    instrument='FUT.US',
    locationCode='FUT.GLOBEX',
    scanCode='TOP_PERC_GAIN')
scanData = ib.reqScannerSubscription(sub)
scanData.updateEvent += onScanData
ib.sleep(60)
ib.cancelScannerSubscription(scanData)
```

Comment: `+=` doesn't mean *increment*, it could also mean *concatenate*, *join*, or whatever the object on the left side wants it to mean.

Comment: [`Event.__iadd__`](https://github.com/erdewit/eventkit/blob/master/eventkit/event.py#L374) is the same as `Event.connect`.

Comment: https://eventkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#eventkit.event.Event.connect

Comment: The object responsible of firing the event keeps a list of all the event handlers that should be invoked when the event occurs. The += operator in this context indicates adding an event handler to the invocation list. You don't use the = operator because you don't want to cancel previously made subscriptions to the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`reqScannerSubscription`](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/62bfdcde4a228788c7f960347c07d25fd5943133/ib_insync/ib.py#L1388) returns an instance of [`ScanDataList`](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/62bfdcde4a228788c7f960347c07d25fd5943133/ib_insync/objects.py#L443). Its [`updateEvent`](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/62bfdcde4a228788c7f960347c07d25fd5943133/ib_insync/objects.py#L406) property is an instance of `eventkit.Event`. It overloads its [`__iadd__`](https://github.com/erdewit/eventkit/blob/master/eventkit/event.py#L374) method to be an alias for [`connect`](https://github.com/erdewit/eventkit/blob/master/eventkit/event.py#L76), which connects a listener to this event.